# Перенос теста внутри DIV

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, ширина в нем установлена 300px. Помещаемый в него текст вытягивается в одну строчку и выходит далеко за границы блока. Как перенести текст по словам таким, образом, чтобы он не выходил за правую границу блока? Пробовалось word-wrap, overflow-wrap со значением break-word - не помогло.

```
<div class="tp-caption emphatic_small_bold sfl randomrotateout" style="width: 150px; word-break: break-all;" data-x="170" data-y="175" data-speed="500" data-start="3500" data-easing="Power4.easeOut">Очень длинный текст здесь</div>
```

То, что показывают инструменты разработчика:

```
element.style {
    width: 150px;
    word-break: break-all;
    border-width: 0px;
    transition: all 0s ease 0s;
    min-height: 0px;
    min-width: 0px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 9px;
    left: 105.652px;
    top: 108.759px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -0.0025, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.tp-caption.emphatic_small_bold {
    position: absolute;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.tp-simpleresponsive .caption, .tp-simpleresponsive .tp-caption {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
.tp-caption {
    z-index: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: word-break: break-all тоже не работает

Comment: Ну тогда нужен код

Comment: Добавил код.. Можно также посмотреть по адресу городнаш.рф , длинный текст размещается в баннере, под заголовком.

Comment: у элемента с классом `tp-caption` нужно убрать `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: или добавить нашему элементу `white-space: normal;`

Comment: white-space: normal сработало

Answer (score 1):

Нужно удалить `white-space: nowrap;` из CSS, это параметр который заставляет писать текст в одну строчку. Вот пример, в котором я закомментировал этот параметр.

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    word-break: break-all;
    border-width: 0px;
    transition: all 0s ease 0s;
    min-height: 0px;
    min-width: 0px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 9px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -0.0025, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.tp-caption.emphatic_small_bold {
    position: absolute;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-family: "Raleway",sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    /*white-space: nowrap; !!!УДАЛИТЬ (я закомментировал)*/
}
.tp-simpleresponsive .caption, .tp-simpleresponsive .tp-caption {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
.tp-caption {
    z-index: 1;
    /*white-space: nowrap; !!!УДАЛИТЬ (я закомментировал)*/
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="tp-caption emphatic_small_bold sfl randomrotateout" style="width: 150px; word-break: break-all;" data-x="170" data-y="175" data-speed="500" data-start="3500" data-easing="Power4.easeOut">Очень длинный текст здесь Очень длинный текст здесь Очень длинный текст здесь Очень длинный текст здесь Очень длинный текст здесь Очень длинный текст здесь Очень длинный текст здесь Очень длинный текст здесь</div>
```